# How to embed HTML code in Tumblr

Tags: html, tumblr

this is my tumblr blog www.lowcoupling.com
It is a blog on computer science and software development. 
In some posts I'd like to show some HTML snippets but when I try to do it through `<pre></pre>` tags Tumblr does not recognize it as plain text but interprets it as a portion of the page HTML.
Is there any way to easily work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple you can just replace  `< by &lt; and > by &gt;` of that HTML snippets and paste in your code afterwards

Comment: :( I guess it is the only way

Comment: this is the easiest way, if you don't like there are 2 other ways: 1. wrap with a textarea, 2. wrap with a xmp tag